# How do I control the variable names in Perl's Data::Dumper?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I've got this simple Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %foo = ( 'abc' => 1 );

print Dumper(\%foo);
```

It outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'abc' => 1
        };
```

How do I make it output this instead?

```
%foo = (
         'abc' => 1
       );
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \%foo ], [ qw(*foo) ] );
```

The extended syntax takes two arrayrefs: one of scalars to dump, and one of names to use.  If the name is prefixed by * and the corresponding scalar is an arrayref or hashref, an array or hash assignment is produced.

Comment: Ah, I had tried sticking everything I could think of (or copy-paste from the perldoc) in between the parentheses, but I hadn't realized that the problem was I was using Dumper() instead of Data::Dumper->Dump().

Answer (score 9):

```
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

print '%foo = '.(Dumper \%foo);
```

Comment: Might be nice to expand this to explain why your code answers the question.

Comment: The simplest and best solution. Like Python's `pformat`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to ysth's answer, you can use Ovid's [Data::Dumper::Names](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper-Names/lib/Data/Dumper/Names.pm) module.

Answer (score 2):

Also, [Data::Dumper::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper-Simple/lib/Data/Dumper/Simple.pm) does roughly that.

Comment: Beware the source filter. It bites.